# Update QueryableCollectionView when item in SQL has been added/Edited/Changed

Tags: c#, wpf

how can I update my QueryableCollectionView when an item in SQL has been added/Edited/Changed? I am using a refresh button which poll down new data. What I want to do is to update the collection view by adding, editing or removing items based on ID.

```
    private void RefreshDataCollection(QueryableCollectionView view)
    {
        var getUpdatedData= await GetUpdatedData();

        foreach (var item in view)
        {
            if (!getUpdatedData.Any(m => m.ID== item.ID))
            {
                this.view.Remove(item);
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in getUpdatedData)
        {
            var itemCopy = View.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.ID== item .ID);

            if (itemCopy != null)
            {
                itemCopy.Title= Item.Title;
            }
            else
            {
                this.View.Add(Item);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my attempt, but I can't get it to work with the datatype QueryableCollectionView. Could someone help me?

Comment: Where do you get the `QueryableCollectionView` from? Modify the `ObservableCollection<T>` source collection instead. And what is `this.view`?

Comment: view is the QueryableCollectionView.

Comment: It depends on what your underlying collection is that this is a view on. If this is not ilist then i think you can't add items and you'll need to change from queryablecollectionview.

Comment: Ok, but I'm curious about since at initial I create a new QueryableCollectionView(observableCollection), how can I update the observablecollection if it get's new data? Do I have to queue a new queryablecollection?

Comment: Please show you you create the QueryableCollectionView and call the RefreshDataCollection method.